# Changing the image source when pressing the back button

Tags: javascript

I have a slider. When clicking next button image is loading.

```
var t=3
        function next_btn(){
            
            t+=3;
            var imgEl = document.querySelectorAll('.lazy');
            for (let a = 0; a < t; a++) {
                if(imgEl[a].getAttribute('data-original')) {
                imgEl[a].setAttribute('src',imgEl[a].getAttribute('data-original'));
                imgEl[a].removeAttribute('data-original'); 
            }
            }
            

        }
```

but when clicking previous button image is not loading.

```
function previous_btn(){
     
            var imgEl = document.querySelectorAll('.lazy');
            
            for (let a =imgEl.length; a >3; a--) {
                if(imgEl[a].getAttribute('data-original')) {
                imgEl[a].setAttribute('src',imgEl[a].getAttribute('data-original'));
                imgEl[a].removeAttribute('data-original'); 
            }
            }
            
           
        }
```

I tried other things but it didn't work. How can I fix?

Comment: I See you are removing attribute `data-original` when click next (`imgEl[a].removeAttribute('data-original')`) , then when click previous you are trying to read  `data-original` from the image `imgEl[a].getAttribute('data-original')` which you removed already .

Comment: But not working when you press the previous button without pressing the next button.

Comment: both next and previous buttons have the same logic, you are removing the attribute `data-original` after setting it to `src` attribute , another click won't work for both buttons.
try to remove the line `imgEl[a].removeAttribute('data-original')`  from both functions and see what happens. 

for the previous button click , I believe it has a problem with `for (let a =imgEl.length; a >3; a--)` specifically in the condition section

Comment: Try using keyCode 37 (left arrow) and keyCode 39 (right arrow) if you want to control the images via your keyboard. `if (e.keycode == 37)` then state the image that you want to be presented